# lists in dictionary and max output

Tags: python, dataframe

output should give:

`combined_dictionary = {"class1" : 116, "class2" : 119, "class5":192, "class9":184,"class56":153}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest approach, I think:

```
>>> combined_dictionary = {}
>>> for name, height in zip(list_1, list_2):
...     combined_dictionary[name] = max(combined_dictionary.get(name, 0), height)
...
>>> combined_dictionary
{'Harry': 167, 'Ron': 190, 'Fred': 187, 'George': 190, 'Jerry': 177}
```

If you wanted to do something with all the heights other than get the `max`, a better approach might be to start by accumulating them into a dict of lists:

```
>>> combined_dictionary = {name: [] for name in list_1}
>>> for name, height in zip(list_1, list_2):
...     combined_dictionary[name].append(height)
...
>>> combined_dictionary = {name: max(heights) for name, heights in combined_dictionary.items()}
>>> combined_dictionary
{'Harry': 167, 'Ron': 190, 'Fred': 187, 'George': 190, 'Jerry': 177}
```

Comment: the first one seems to be a good way of doing it, may I know what the 0 in the (name, 0) bracket is for? The second way is quite informative as well!

Comment: ```combined_dictionary = {name: max(heights) for name, heights in list_1 and list_2}``` # I was also trying the dictionary comprehension approach but I get an invalid syntax error, so I am assuming this won't be right.

Comment: `get(name, 0)` means "get the value for key `name`, unless `name` isn't in the dictionary in which case get `0`".

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over each element in the list and use `max()` to retain the highest height seen:

```py
import math

list_1 = ["Harry", "Harry", "Harry", "Ron" , "Ron" , "Ron", "Fred","Fred", "George", "Jerry"]
list_2 = [158, 167, 145, 177, 187, 190, 167, 187, 190, 177]

max_values = {}
for name, height in zip(list_1, list_2):
    max_values[name] = max(height, max_values.get(name, -math.inf))

# Prints {'Harry': 167, 'Ron': 190, 'Fred': 187, 'George': 190, 'Jerry': 177}
print(max_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve what you want with:

```
heights_dict = {}
for i, item in enumerate(list_1):
    if item not in heights_dict:
        heights_dict[item] = list_2[i]
        continue 
    if heights_dict[item] < list_2[i]:
        heights_dict[item] = list_2[i]

print(heights_dict)

{'Harry': 167, 'Ron': 190, 'Fred': 187, 'George': 190, 'Jerry': 177}
```